# Работа с xml в postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, файлы, postgresql

Есть документ в формате xml, я кладу его в таблицу postgresql.
Кладу вот так:

```
create or replace function bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;


 insert into mydocs(docform,content)
 values (3, convert_from(bytea_import('D:/html/ex08.xml'), 'utf-8'));
```

Необходимо изменить файл. Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list_of_items>
<item id="1"><first/>Первый</item>
<item id="2">Второй <sub_item>подпункт 1</sub_item></item>
<item id="3">Третий</item>
<item id="4"><last/>Последний</item>
</list_of_items>
```

Необходимо вытащить из этого файла текст и положить его в другую таблицу, тоесть:

`Первый` положить в колонку 1

`Второй` положить в колонку 2

`подпункт 1` положить в колонку 3

`Третий` положить в колонку 4

`Последний`положить в колонку 5

Вот такой запрос

```
WITH x(col) AS (
        SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <list_of_items>
        <item id="1"><first/>first</item>
        <item id="2">second <sub_item>subsecond 1</sub_item></item>
        <item id="3">third</item>
        <item id="4"><last/>last</item>
        </list_of_items>
        '::xml
    ), interpreted as (
        SELECT xpath('.//item/text()', col) AS val,
               xpath('.//sub_item/text()', col) AS val2
        FROM   x
    )
    SELECT val[1] as col1, val[2] as col2, val2[1] as col3, val[3] as col4, val[4] as col5
    FROM interpreted
    ;
```

дает такой ответ

```
col1  |  col2   |    col3     | col4  | col5 
-------+---------+-------------+-------+----
first | second  | subsecond 1 | third | last
(1 row)
```

Насчёт алгоритма.

Возможно, что есть способ в xml искать текст в таких вот строках

```
<item id="1"><first/>Первый</item> -- здесь текст - слово первый
```

Соответственно строки без текста удаляются, а из строк с текстом вытаскивается текст и кидается в другую таблицу.
Только способа не знаю, если он конечно есть.

Ещё один пример xml файла:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

Из него хочу получить

```
             Gambardella, Matthew
             XML Developer's Guide
             Computer
             44.95
             2000-10-01
             An in-depth look at creating applications 
             with XML.
```

Последний текст = запись таблицы.

Каждая строка последнего текста = колонка этой записи.

В идеале ещё конечно, чтобы эта колонка называлась так-же, как и в <таких скобках> в xml файле.

```
author               |  title                 |    genre |
---------------------+------------------------+----------+
Gambardella, Matthew | XML Developer's Guide  | Computer | 
(1 row)
```

вот так ( пару колонок не дописал, не обессудьте )

Comment: Так *искать текст* по каким параметрам-то? Как вы разделяете значения для отдельных колонок? Возможно, стоит привести ещё один пример XML и ожидаемого результата.

Comment: @D-side исправил, спасибо